# plus sign escape c++

Tags: c++, loops, escaping, operands

hi guys im having difficulties about plus sign while getting input. here im dealing with reverse polish notation calculator. what i have to is to take input as "3 2 + $" which means(in an easy way) add 3 and 2 and show them. i tried to use stringstreams, while(cin). now im trying to get input one by one;

```
int num;
char ch;
while (cin)
    {
        if (cin >> num)
        {
            cout<<num;
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin >> ch;
            cout << ch;
        }
    }
}
```

it doesnt work for + and - and works for * and /. but i need those operands too. i tried istringstream by gettingline. it didnt see + or - either.

Comment: Did you consider that + and - can before be part of a number: -10 is still an integer...

Comment: Get each argument as a string, and test the string for what kind of argument it is.

Comment: `std::cin >> num` only fails once it's done extracting the + or - and realizes there's no following number.

Comment: you can use something like this : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cad8dcb47b22b80f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample code this line worry me `while (cin)` (must certain you would have and infinite cycle), in the sample code bellow (i added that when enter a blank line the program ends).

cin will get the input one word by one word, when you write in the console `3 2 + $` when you call `cin >> somevariable;` would get 4 results: **3** then **2** then **+** and last **$**. Other problem when reading polish notation is that you can't predict if the next token would be number or operator, you could get: `3 2 + $` but `3 2 2 + * $` too. For this reason you need a container to storage the operands.

Here is a little working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string read;
    std::stack<int> nums;
    while (cin >> read) {
        if (read.empty()) {
            break;
        }
        else if (read == "$") {
            std::cout << nums.top() << std::endl;
        }
        else if (read == "+" || read == "-" || read == "*" || read == "/") {
            if (nums.size() < 2) {
            } // error code here

            int n1 = nums.top();
            nums.pop();
            int n2 = nums.top();
            nums.pop();

            if (read == "+")
                nums.push(n2 + n1);
            if (read == "-")
                nums.push(n2 - n1);
            if (read == "*")
                nums.push(n2 * n1);
            if (read == "/")
                nums.push(n2 / n1);
        }
        else {
            try {
                nums.push(boost::lexical_cast<int>(
                    read)); // you should add convertion excepcion code
            }
            catch (...) {

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```